# AADSTS65005: Dynamic scope is invalid - Files.Read

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I am getting "AADSTS65005: Dynamic scope is invalid " for scope Files.Read

If i use Files.ReadWrite AzureAD OpenID Connect Authorization endpoint accepts it

Does any one know what is wrong with

URL i am accessing is

https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access+Files.Read&state=12345&nonce=678910

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. One note though--your authorize endpoints has to contain the {tenant}:   https: //login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize. Per the docs, this must be common (work + personal accounts), organizations (work or school accounts only), consumers (personal accounts only), or the specific Azure AD tenant. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints

Comment: There was a temporary issue yesterday with consent, @aaskash wasnik, which hit me as well. This is now fixed today. Can you please tell me if that still does not work for you?

Comment: Thanks Jean. As you mentioned it was temporary issue and resolved next day when i tried to test. sorry for replying so late.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line(add the base url):

```
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/files.read+offline_access
```